# Error in adding records to access from c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

heyguys,

im totally new to this... i wanted to add my records from a winform to an access Database which is already a datasource but ended up in an error where it says:

> OleDBException was unhandled and belw which it says "Syntax error in
>   INSERT INTO statement."

denoting the line:

```
da.Update(ds1, "Table1");
```

my coding is:

```
        int MaxRows = 0;
        int inc = 0;

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            ds1 = new DataSet();

            con.ConnectionString = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/anchu.accdb";
            string sql = "SELECT * From Table1";
            da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);

            con.Open();

            da.Fill(ds1, "Table1");
            //NavigateRecords();

            con.Close();
            //con.Dispose();
        }
        /*private void NavigateRecords()
        {
            DataRow drow = ds1.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0];

            textBox1.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            textBox3.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
            textBox4.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();





        }*/


        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb;
            cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

            DataRow drow = ds1.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();
            drow[0] = textBox1.Text;
            drow[1] = textBox2.Text;
            drow[2] = textBox3.Text;
            drow[3] = textBox4.Text;

            ds1.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Add(drow);

            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
            inc = MaxRows - 1;

            da.Update(ds1, "Table1");

            MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please have a look to the table structure.
It seems, the table fields didn't match.

E.g: If you have an auto column and you add a value to that column, it will throw exception.
Moreover even if the table columns match, check the datatype and max length also.

Hope this solves.

cheers

Comment: can you post the table structure you are using for table1?

Comment: yeah sure...how should i post it?

Comment: i posted the table structure sandip

Comment: I still couldn't see the table structure. Where did you post it?

Comment: i posted it as a picture as i edited in the original post sandip

Comment: one sec... this is the table structure:

SLNO           Text
Name           Text
Address        Text
Contact Number Text

Answer (score 0):

`OleDbCommandBuilder` is not great at building statements for DB systems like Access that have different syntax requirements than PSQL or TSQL.  I would add a breakpoint after you generate the `CommandBuilder` and look at the SQL it generates to see if it is correct syntax for Access.

You may be better off building the INSERT statement yourself rather than assuming that the command builder will build it correctly for you.